# How to use require() in html

Tags: javascript, html, require

I try to use require() in html. I try to use require in JS but I get the following error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
I wonder how can I use require function on client browser. And there is no way to use require in client browser except requireJS??

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const endpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('https://kr.object.ncloudstorage.com');
const region = 'kr-standard';
const access_key = 'access_key';
const secret_key = 'secret_key';

const S3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: endpoint,
    region: region,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: access_key,
        secretAccessKey: secret_key
    }
});

const bucket_name = 'together-image';
const local_file_path = './image.jpg';


(async () => {

    let object_name = 'image.jpg';
    // create folder
    await S3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucket_name,
        Key: object_name
    }).promise();

    object_name = 'image.jpg';

    // upload file
    await S3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucket_name,
        Key: object_name,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Body: fs.createReadStream(local_file_path)
    }).promise();
})();
```

I appreciate with your help in advance

Comment: You cannot use require in vanilla javascript. You can use npm packages only in a node project. If you want to use the package in your website, you should use a web framework. Also, you cannot use the fs package in client side javascript

Comment: You can use require if you are using CommonJS modules, but in your case it would be useless by the way if you are trying to execute that code in the browser, since the 'fs' module won't work in browsers, it's a nodeJS module made to work on file system ( mainly read and write operations ). If you don't have a dedicated web server, you can try to upload your project to a serverless environment like Vercel or Netlify and use their serverless functions to execute that kind of code, it will work there, since they call them on their NodeJS web servers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless a module bundler is used. I recommend using aws sdk for browser in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html